# How to update Ruby version on my Rack based server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, capistrano, rack

I use Rack on my server.
I use Passenger on my server.
I use Capistrano on my server.
I do not yet use RVM on my server.
I currently have ruby 1.8.7 install on the server, but would like to update to 1.9.2 because of a gem. Technically, I think I have both, but ruby -v yields 1.9.2.

How do I update Ruby on the server so that Rack will use the new version?

I updated Ruby on the system, but Rack still uses gems from 1.8 ie.
"home/USER/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. You must edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and change the value of PassengerRuby to the new location of ruby. In my case, since I also installed RVM, the new dir was /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby